# Как обработать ситуацию так, чтобы приложение не грохнулось при повторном освобождении памяти?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Если представить ситуацию, где по случайности (либо по неосторожности, или по причине не хватки опыта и т.п.) память освобождается повторно (delete ptr;) (да хороший разраб такого не допустит, в хорошо продуманных архитектурных решениях ткого недолжно произойти вовсе) как обработать ситуацию, чтобы приложение не грохнулось?

Comment: Достаточно не освобождать память повторно. И нет, приложение не обязательно грохается при таком сценарии, это происходит в лучшем случае.

Comment: @VTT Прочитайте внимательно вопрос, все знают, что не надо повторно освобождать! Вопрос в том, как обработать данную теоретическую ситуацию!

Comment: Эту ситуацию нельзя обработать, так как тут имеется неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @VTT спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Обнуляйте указатель после `delete`. `delete nullptr` - допустимая операция

Comment: А ещё можно использоваться ТОЛЬКО умные указатели для работы с памятью

Comment: @vegorov Вопрос не в том, как избежать данной ситуации, я и сам знаю до хрена трюков, и не допускаю такого в своих проектах, вопрос в том можно ли обработать или нет повторное освобождение (в теории, если такое по какой то причине случилось)!!!

Comment: Можно обрабатывать сигналы SIGSEGV или как они там называются

Comment: @vegorov есть живой пример, и/или ссылка на руководство??

Comment: @vegorov Повторное освобождение памяти не обязательно приводит к SIGSEGV или каким-то другим конкретным последствиям. И даже если бы приводило, то обработать SIGSEGV иначе как аварийным завершением приложения вряд ли получится.

Comment: @VTT - А я и не говорил как именно их обрабатывать.  Я с Вами согласен по поводу завершения приложения.

Comment: @James [signal-handling-in-linux](http://www.alexonlinux.com/signal-handling-in-linux). Про Windows и Visual Studio к сожалению вообще ничего не знаю. Ну кроме того что они платные

Comment: @vegorov Спасибо!

Comment: если уж в метках стоит visual c++, то у майкрософта есть механизм как раз для этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942970/%D0%A1-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-delete/943015#943015