# Исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. t было 0x8123

Tags: c++

Имеется стек и требуется удалить из него элементы с четными числами. Стек заполняется рандомными числами. При запуске функции удаление происходит исключение.

```
struct Stack {
    int info;
    Stack* next;
};
void DelEven(Stack* p) {
    Stack* t = p;
    Stack* t1 = t;
    while (t != NULL) {
        if (t->info % 2 != 0) { // исключение тут
            t1 = t;
            t = t->next;
        }
        else {
            if (t == p) {
                p = p->next;
                delete t;
            }
            else {
                t1->next = t->next;
                delete t;
                t = t1->next;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: А как вы представляете себе выход из вашего цикла wile?

Comment: На конце стека t будет равняться NULL, что будет восприниматься как false. Мне не понятно, почему в половине случаев запуска программы, функция работает корректно, а в другой половине выдает исключение...

Comment: я просто напомню: вызов delete не устанавливает указатель в NULL

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942970/%d0%a1-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-delete/943015#943015 - к вопросу откуда у вас 0х8123

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Спасибо большое, не видел очевидного.